# How do I implement tags for a post?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

So I have a Post and Tag class, which should be many-many. But I can't get anything tags to show.

Post class

```
public class Post
{
    public Post()
    {
        this.Tags = new List<Tag>();
    }

    public int PostID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

}
```

Tag class :

```
public class Tag
{
    public int TagID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

And part of my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Title,Body,Tags")] BlogInputModel input)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        Post post = new Post
        {
            Title = input.Title,
            Body = input.Body,
            DateTime = DateTime.Now
        };
        post.Tags.Clear();
        foreach (string tag in input.Tags.Split(' '))
        {
            post.Tags.Add(GetTag(tag));
        }

        db.Posts.Add(post);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = post.PostID });
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var post = db.Posts.Where(x => x.PostID == id).First();
    return View(post);
}

private Tag GetTag(string tagName)
{
    return db.Tags.Where(x => x.Name == tagName).FirstOrDefault() ?? new Tag { Name = tagName };
}
```

And here is my context class

```
public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public BlogContext() : base("BlogContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
           .HasMany(t => t.Tags)
           .WithMany(p => p.Posts)
           .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("PostID")
                  .MapRightKey("TagID")
                  .ToTable("PostTags"));
    }
}
```

I'm getting exceptions any way I try to fix it and nothing works. Shouldn't EF just create the PostTags table and everything should connect?

Or do I have to get rid of the modelBuilder code and create my own third table, but if so, how can I pass the ID of a post to the tags?

Comment: What is the message of the exception ?

Comment: All sorts of different things because I keep changing stuff. Just trying to find out if my logic is correct

Comment: If you are just testing EF make sure you have a problem before posting a question in SO

Comment: Open the package manager console and run the following commands :

- Enable-Migrations
- Add-Migration Init
- Update-Database 

Then check if the database is created

Comment: Yeah we really need a concrete scenario with exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Shouldn't EF just create the PostTags table and everything should connect?
>
> Or do I have to get rid of the modelBuilder code and create my own third table, but if so, how can I pass the ID of a post to the tags?

EF is clever enough to know that a new table is needed to link `Tag` and `Post` because you created:

- `IList<Tag>`in `Post`
- `ICollection<Post>` in `Tag`.

Then you can remove the code you write in `OnModelCreating` and EF will create a new table to link `Tag` and `Post`.

The cons of removing the code in `OnModelCreating` are :

- you don't know in advance how EF will name your table `PostTags` or `TagPosts`. Imagine you need to create a SQL view related to the link table, it will be cool to know what will be the name of the table.
- you don't know what will be the order of the composed key when it is created because you will need to use the same order when using `DbSet.Find` method. This method need the keys in the same order they were created on the linked table.

Answer (score 0):

I have example from my project. I used table PostTag to connect Post with Tags. You can also configure many-to-many relationship with code first or fluent api where connection table will be autogenerated. [See example](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PostTag> TagPosts { get; set; }
}

public class PostTag
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index("IX_PostTag", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index("IX_PostTag", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public int TagId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PostId")]
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TagId")]
    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: OK but in this example. How do I assign Posts to have Tags? When I create a Post, how do I get the Tag IDs to be in the Post PostTags collection?

Comment: Hi, you can download complete source code for my example from https://github.com/EdinMahmutovic/Clean-Blog-MVC In administration area you have post crud operations. This is my test project, used for learning mvc...Login data:(admin@admin.com, pass:Edin123!)